# Why does the colorpicker js not load with fancybox modal?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, color-picker

So Im trying to add a colorpicker to the fancybox image viewer to change the background color dyanmically. Ive made it display the colorpicker input in the correct place, but the js doesnt seem to load and I just get a standard input box.

Here is the js fiddle for it
http://jsfiddle.net/22Tre/1/

Im using the spectrum color picker

http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/

https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum

The colorpicker loads and works fine when I put the

```
<input id='colorpicker' />
```

In my page, but like I said when its gets inserted dynamically with fancybox only an input is displayed.
Any ideas you geniuses?

Comment: In your fiddle, where is the `spectrum()` init code? ... and most importantly, did you load the spectrum js and css files??? ...anyway, try initializing spectrum inside the `beforeShow` fancybox callback

Comment: @JFK init code is at the bottom of the js window. The resources are being loaded from the external resources tab on the left. Ill try the beforeShow idea.

Comment: updated fiddle with beforeLoad. Doesn't seem to help. http://jsfiddle.net/22Tre/3/

Comment: I never said `beforeLoad` if you read properly

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

You must use afterLoad callback function. Heres the working example...

http://jsfiddle.net/22Tre/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     'afterLoad': function () {
         $("#colorpicker").spectrum({
             color: 'rgba(255, 251, 204, 0.8)'
         });
     },

     helpers: {
         overlay: {
             css: {
                 'background': 'rgba(255, 251, 204, 0.8)'
             }
         }
     }
 });

});
```

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/22Tre/6/ working with `beforeShow` as suggested in my first comment ;)